# How to mount a CD with QNX on a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, mount, qnx

I'm trying to mount an iso image on my Virtual Machine running QNX.

How do I do this?

I'm using VMWare Player. I've loaded the iso file under player > removable devices > cd/dvd > settings, but I can't find it in my QNX file system.

I'm new to QNX, and to Linux to which it is similar, but I've been able to find most of the Linux commands I will need. However, unless I can find the name of the cd drive, I can't mount it.

Comment: QNX is not "based off Linux", it's like Linux a Unix alike OS. Fyi, QNX is *older* than Linux.

Comment: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide%2Ftopic%2Fhardware_CDROM_DVD.html

Comment: Not really programming-related - try http://superuser.com ?

Comment: Any change you are a coop at blackberry?

Comment: @robbmj nope, just using QNX for a project (although I am a co-op student)

Answer (score 3):

If you use default QNX image then CD-ROM driver does not run automatically. There are two ways for use CD-ROM depending on bus: IDE and SATA. But for iso image, I mean not for use host CD-ROM, you can change the bus of CD-ROM device to IDE and then do these actions:

1. Run the driver by

   ```
   devb-eide cdrom
   ```
2. Mount your CD-ROM device by

   ```
   mount -t cd /dev/cd0 /cd
   ```

Comment: What does the -tcd option do? I also can't cd into the directory, although it claims to mount successfully.

Comment: @GreySage, -tcd option means filesystem type = "cd", read **-t cd**.
See `sloginfo` for investigation, there are many ways what this can be.